Proof of the generalised $D$-dimensional virial theorem for an effective potential
In Ch.12, Pg.257 of Weinberg's Classical Solutions in Quantum Field Theory : Solitons and Instantons in High Energy Physics he states that in $D$ spatial dimensions, where the action can be written as the sum of a kinetic part and a potential part: $$I_K = \int{\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \rho}\right)^2} d\tau d^D x,\qquad I_V = \int (V(\phi) - V_{fv}(\phi)) d\tau d^D x$$ then $I_K = \frac{1-D}{1+D} I_V$ from "the same manipulations that led to Derrick's theorem", but provides no further proof. This generalised virial theorem would be very useful in approximating the action of a bounce for a specific potential, but I feel uncomfortable using this without proof. The standard virial theorem holds if the potential is of the form $V = Ar^N$, which is not the case here as the potential is a quartic with multiple terms. How would you go about proving this and does this hold for any generic potential with up to quartic terms?

More on Derrick's theorem.

This helped! The derivation is basically just This stack exchange question because we can treat $\tau$ as a 4th spatial dimension in Euclidean space. Thank you!
